# How it iterate over a matrix using a function in R?

Tags: r

I have created a function to order a vector of length 2, using the following code

```
x = (c(6,2))
orders = function(x){
  for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
  if(x[i+1] < x[i]){
    return(c(x[i+1], x[i]))} else{
      (return(x))
  }}}


orders(x)
```

I have been asked to use this function to process a dataset with 2 columns as follows.  Iterate over the rows of the
data set, and if the element in the 2nd column of row *i* is less than the element in the first
column of row *i*, switch the order of the two entries in the row by making a suitable call to
the function you just wrote.

I've tried using the following code

```
set.seed(1128719)
data=matrix(rnorm(20),byrow=T,ncol=2)
df = for (i in 1:2) {
  for(j in 1:10){
    data = orders(c(x[i], x[j]))
    return(data)
  }

}
```

The output is null. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `for` loops always return `NULL`. `return(...)` is only applicable within a function. The `apply` function allows you to operate on a matrix row-wise (`apply(mtx, 1, FUN)`), column-wise (`apply(mtx, 2, FUN)`). (It does multi-dim arrays, so it goes even further than that.)

Comment: Ok I will get rid of return... but maybe I'm writing the code wrong, in the question I'm asked it says to iterate, so I thought I would use for loops... which I've used before and it never gave me back NULL

Comment: I don't know that I would write it this way in the long-term, but for the purpose of learning how this works ... did you know that you can re-assign a submatrix? For instance, `mtx[4,1:2] <- mtx[4,2:1]` will swap the first two columns in row 4. (oops ... had them backwards ... corrected :-)

Comment: Is the input vector always of length 2?

Comment: input vector for what?

Comment: For the function `orders`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified your code a bit but tried to keep the 'style' the same
Ther is no need for a loop
`i in 1:(length(x)-1)` always evaluates to
`for i in 1:1` and `i` will only take the value of 1.

```
orders = function(x){

      # Since the function will only work on vectors of length 2
      # its good practice to raise an error right at the start
      #   
      if (length(x) != 2) {
        stop("x must be vector of lenght 2")
      } 

  if (x[2] < x[1]) {
    return(c(x[2], x[1]))
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

orders(c(6, 2))


set.seed(1128719)
data <- matrix(rnorm(20),byrow=T,ncol=2)
```

The for loop itself cant be assigned to a variable
But we use the loop to mutate the matrix 'data'
in place

```
for (row in 1:nrow(data)) {
  data[row, ] <- orders(data[row,])
}

data
```

## Edit:

This is the input:

```
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.04142965  0.2377140
[2,] -0.76237866 -0.8004284
[3,]  0.18700893 -0.6800310
[4,]  0.76499646  0.4430643
[5,]  0.09193440 -0.2592316
[6,]  1.17478053 -0.4044760
[7,] -1.62262500  0.1652850
[8,] -1.54848857  0.7475451
[9,] -0.05907252 -0.8324074
[10,] -1.11064318 -0.1148806
```

This is the output i get:

```
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] -0.04142965  0.23771403
[2,] -0.80042842 -0.76237866
[3,] -0.68003104  0.18700893
[4,]  0.44306433  0.76499646
[5,] -0.25923164  0.09193440
[6,] -0.40447603  1.17478053
[7,] -1.62262500  0.16528496
[8,] -1.54848857  0.74754509
[9,] -0.83240742 -0.05907252
[10,] -1.11064318 -0.11488062
```

Comment: that doesn't switch the order of values so that the lowest values are in column 1 and the highest values in column 2

Comment: I think it does, as seen in the output shown in the edit

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways of ordering the 2 columns matrix.

This is the test matrix posted in the question.

```
set.seed(1128719)
data <- matrix(rnorm(20), byrow = TRUE, ncol = 2)
```

## 1. With a function `orders`.

The function expects as input a 2 element vector. If they are out of order, return the vector with its elements reversed, else return the vector as is.

```
orders <- function(x){
  stopifnot(length(x) == 2)
  if(x[2] < x[1]){
    x[2:1]
  }else{
    x
  }
}
```

Test the function.

```
x <- c(6,2)
orders(x)
#[1] 2 6
```

Now with the matrix `data`.

```
df1 <- t(apply(data, 1, orders))
```

## 2. Vectorized code.

Creates a logical index with `TRUE` whenever the elements are out of order and reverse only those elements.

```
df2 <- data
inx <- data[,2] < data[,1]
df2[inx, ] <- data[inx, 2:1]
```

The results are the same.

```
identical(df1, df2)
#[1] TRUE
```